# How can I stream music files from Android Phone via wifi on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, android, rhythmbox, steam

1. Have a Wi-Fi network at home
2. Have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my laptop connected to home Wi-Fi
3. Have an Android based cell phone connected to home WiFi

Can I play (stream) my music files stored in the cell phone via WiFi on my Rhythmbox Music Player or any other free software on my laptop?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I have already done extensive search but couldn't find solution to my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I publish an application on Google Play called AirSong. This application lets you listen to the music you have on your device at any PC with a browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera). You can find this application here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autoindent.airsong

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [VLC Direct Pro Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlcforandroid.vlcdirectprofree&hl=en)

It can stream music and videos (and also photos)

The description says :

> - Remote control VideoLan VLC from your Phone/Tablet (play, pause, stop, volume, fullscreen, change video/song, dvd menu control, change
>     audio tracks, change subtitle tracks, etc.)
> - Streaming from Android to Computer (Video, music and photos)
> - Its internal video player allows streaming content Computer to Android (Video, music and photos)
> - Subtitles supported